# .net Generic List optimization relating to capacity

Tags: c#, .net, list, optimization, collections

I'm currently working with an app that will do the following.

```
// Initialize a list: 
myList = new List<aPoint>;
while(WeHaveMoreData)
   myList->Add(ReturnNext1000Points());
```

I have no way of knowing the total size of the list from the beginning.  From what I've read, `List<>` is the best way to handle this much data incoming (could be upwards of 500k records).

I'm wondering if I should handle the capicity of the list (give it initial values, or increase the cap if it needs it)?

How do I approach optimizing such a procedure?

Comment: To add to the question, I'm working under .net 2.0 constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an approximation of the total records you could set the capacity of the list otherwise leave it to grow. It is pretty optimized, just ensure you don't run out of memory. Another approach is to use a lazy iterator which won't load the entire list in memory:

```
public IEnumerable<aPoint> GetPoints()
{
    while(WeHaveMoreData)
    {
        yield return new aPoint();
    }
}
```

It is only once you start iterating that records will begin to be fetched, one by one and released immediately:

```
foreach (var point in GetPoints())
{
    /// TODO: do something with the point
}
```

Comment: That would be an ideal solution, unfortunately, I'm programming in VC++/2.0, no yeild operations, and the "GetNext1000" is an unmanaged C function call pulling in data from Shmem

Comment: @greggorob64, why is your question tagged with C# then? Because of this tag I assumed that it might be an *acceptable* language for you.

Comment: You have a point.  If I mark it as C++, questions rarely get looked at.  A valid constraint I could put on the question is using C#2.0.  The languages don't diverge (that much) until that point.

Comment: @greggorob64: When you're talking optimization at this level, the different language mechanics--especially memory management--and compiler optimizations diverge a lot. Gaming the question tags so it is seen more may get more views, but won't get you a good enough answer.

Comment: It's a fair point, but its not gaming.  The heap optimizations any clr languages aren't going to change drastically enough to warrant that.  The solution would be valid for either.

Answer (score 2):

First rule: premature optimization is the root of all evil. If perfomance is not an issue leave it as is. Overwise you should try set initial size of list to about `AverageExpectedSize/0.7`.

Answer (score 1):

I also think you can't optimize it much.. I guess you could do slightly better in some specific cases, so I have a question - what do you do with the data afterwards? Also - do you want to optimize for memory or speed?

A typical list implementation will grow capacity by a factor of 2x every time, so maybe you could save some space by having a `List<aPoint[]>`, which would have much fewer elements, so it would be less likely that you have a few 100k of spare capacity. But that would only matter if you were just about to run out of memory - it's likely that much more memory is spent on the data itself in any case..

Comment: The data is analyzed and added to a Datavisualization.Charting histogram

Comment: So do you actually need the whole set of points at once for the analysis?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would say that if you don't know the number of elements within say +/- 20% then you are probably should just add blindly to the List instead of guessing the capacity.

List is different than an array when it comes to matters of adding when at capacity.  Remember that the List will double its capacity once you exceed the capacity.  So for example, if your list has a current capacity of 128 elements and you add an element that makes it 129 elements, the list will resize its capacity to 256 elements.  Then for the next 128 Adds you don't resize the list at all.  Once you get to 257, it will double to 512, and the process repeats itself.

Thus you will have O(log(n)) resizes to your list.